# Why no render partial with UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I need partial render with ajax; I don't know what is wrong. ¿What is the problem?

My code:

### ascx

```
<div id="temasatratar" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');"><h1>Temas a tratar</h1></div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### ascx.cs

```
    protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number = rnd.Next(0, 99999);
        Label1.Text = "Best "+number;
    }
```

Any suggest?

My application: Sharepoint - Visual web part / C# / Asp.Net / Visual Studio

Comment: When do you want to update that label?

Comment: I want to update the label when the client do click on the div with the id "temasatratar".

Answer (score 2):

I would use a fake-button that is invisible as trigger for the `UpdatePanel`:

```
<div id="temasatratar" onclick="__doPostBack('fakeButton', '');"><h1>Temas a tratar</h1></div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="fakeButton" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="foo" OnClick="fakeButton_Click" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fakeButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now this click-event is handled in an async postback when the user clicks on the div.

```
protected void fakeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // you are in an asynchronous postback now
}
```

Comment: Error message: El tipo 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' no tiene ninguna propiedad pública cuyo nombre sea 'AsyncPostBackTrigger'. / System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel haven't public property with the name AsyncPostBackTrigger

Comment: @Darkering: I have forgotten the `Triggers` part. Edited my answer.

Comment: And the UpdatePanel1_Load?

Comment: @Darkering: Is just an event that exists for every control(e.g. `Page_Load`) but has nothing to do with your click event on the div. Since the div is outside the `UpdatePanel` it would not even cause an update when it would be a server control like a `Button`. Therefore you need the explicit `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

Comment: First: Thanks for your answer!

But: 
The page refresh completely. the changed code is:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="fakeButton" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="foo" OnClick="fakeButton_Click" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fakeButton" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: and 
`protected void fakeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Random rnd=new Random();
int number=rnd.Next(0, 99999);
Label1.Text="Best "+number;
}`

Comment: @Marketing: sorry, i cannot help further since I'm on the way home and currently writing on a phone. Good luck.